# jquery dialog alert before unload or when browser window closed

Tags: jquery

I have a chat application,i want that whenver user accidentaly closes the browser i want to give him a jquery dialog alert before the window closes and do the necessary clean up operations.Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent the user to change page with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102618/how-to-prevent-the-user-to-change-page-with-jquery)

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, this following script use jQuery namespace...

```
jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.returnValue = "Attention !\nVous n'avez pas sauver vos paramètres.\nSi vous appuyer sur OK, vous perdrez les informations en cours d'utilisation...\n\nLa fenêtre est sur le point de se fermer";
    return event.returnValue;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you'llhave to use `window.onbeforeunload` event to get this.

have a look on this [page](http://jonstjohn.com/node/23)

example usage from that page bound to a form

```
function setConfirmUnload(on) {

     window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? unloadMessage : null;

}

function unloadMessage() {

     return 'You have entered new data on this page.  If you navigate away from this page without first saving your data, the changes will be lost.';

}


$(document).ready(function() {

     $(':input',document.myForm).bind("change", function() { setConfirmUnload(true); }); // Prevent accidental navigation away
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[View the discussion here](http://www.nabble.com/Detect-browser-close-event-td8447562s27240.html)

Basically, you end up using code like this:

```
jQuery(window).unload(function(e) {
  var chg = jQuery(".crayon-changed");
  if (chg.length && uniConfirm(configCrayons.txt.sauvegarder)) {
    chg.next().find('form').submit();
  }
});
```

[Here is a link](http://zone.spip.org/trac/spip-zone/browser/_plugins_/_stable_/crayons/javascript/crayons.js) to the javascript code here (as shown in the thread i linked to above)