# jQuery plugin for preventing users leaving a page with unsaved data with a dialog?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery 1.4.4 and I'm trying to find a plugin that will warn users when navigating away from a form with unsaved changes.  I attempted to code it myself, but ran into issues with window.beforeunload and IE 8.

I need it to not have a restrictive license like GPL as this will be a commercial app and free if possible.

Afermath: I ended up using the [dirty forms plugin](http://mal.co.nz/code/jquery-dirty-forms/) after getting past a configuration issue thanks to help from their team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dirty Forms --> https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms

I have not used this personally but looks what you require :)

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102618/how-to-prevent-the-user-to-change-page-with-jquery

Comment: I've got some similar code that works in Firefox, but not IE 8. However, the setup of the page/form is such that it fires on everything, including a dropdown box before the rest of the data loads up. I'm trying to find a solution that a more flexible plugin will solve.